# git stash restoring index state of deleted and renamed files

Tags: git, git-stash

When stashing staged deleted or renamed files, and then unstashing them, they are restored in both their deleted and non deleted state.

In the following example state:

```
$ git status s

A  file0
D  file1
R  file2 -> file3
?? file4
```

running `git stash push -k -u` and then `git stash pop --index` will leave me with in the following state:

```
$ git status s

A  file0
D  file1
R  file2 -> file3
?? file1
?? file2
?? file4
```

I would expect to end up in the original state, without the deleted files reappearing as untracked after `pop`.

Any way around this?

Edit:
Here's a script that recreates the issue (tested on Mac OS X 10.13.2 with git 2.16.1)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo -e "\nInitializing a fresh git dir..."
mkdir gitStashIssue && cd $_
rm -rf * .*
git init


echo -e "\nPreparing git state for test..."
# Create files and commit them
echo 'abc' > file1
echo 'aabbcc' > file2
echo 'aaabbbccc' > file3
echo 'aaaabbbbcccc' > file4
git add .
git commit -m 'initial commit'

# Make changes and add them to stage
echo `cat file1` >> file1
echo `cat file2` >> file2
git add .

# Make another change to a staged file without
# staging it, making it partially staged
echo `cat file1` >> file1

# Delete and rename files
git rm file3
git mv file4 fileRenamed

# Add untracked file
echo "untracked" > untrackedFile

# git status -s should now show
# MM file1
# M  file2
# D  file3
# R  file4 -> fileREnamed
# ?? untrackedFile

echo -e "\nCurrent git status is:"
git status -s

echo -e "\nStasing changes..."
git stash save -u -k

# git status -s should now show
# M  file1
# M  file2
# D  file3
# R  file4 -> fileREnamed
# ?? file3
# ?? file4

echo -e "\ngit status after stashing files is:"
git status -s

echo -e "\ncleaning up deleted and renamed files..."
git clean ./ -f

echo -e "\ngit status after cleanup:"
git status -s

echo -e "\nCommiting unstashed changes..."
git commit -m 'commit unstashed changes'

# This causes a conflict in file1
# git status -s should now show
# UU file1
# ?? untrackedFile
git stash pop --index

echo -e "\ngit status after unstashing:"
git status -s
```

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this behavior.  Are you applying to the same commit with a clean work tree (i.e. right after stashing, as you show)?  When I do this, it puts the worktree in the expected state...

Comment: This should help recreating the issue:https://pastebin.com/jxFMH3CS

Answer (score 4):

Remember: git does not track file renames. It tracks file contents.

When the index contains a deletion and a creation for different files with the same contents, git's rename detection will (probably) conclude that's a rename, and helpfully display it as such. This doesn't actually change what's in the index, though. What "really" happened was indeed a deletion-then-creation, git is just trying to display it more helpfully.

Try it yourself:

```
$ cp file1 boink
$ rm file1
$ git add .
$ git status
```

Has the same effect as:

```
$ git mv file1 boink
$ git status
```

This rename detection only works on things that have been added to the index. Do `git reset` now and you'll see what I mean:

```
$ git reset
$ git status
Changes not staged for commit:
        deleted:    file1

Untracked files:
        boink
```

We can use the git command `git ls-files` to list the files present in the index. In effect, these are the files git considers existent at the moment.
When we have a rename staged as above, the output from this is:

```
# git ls-files
boink
file2
file3
file4
```

As far as the index is concerned, file1 no longer exists. We deleted it, and then we created `boink`. `git status` is friendly and shows us the results of rename detection, but remember that the index doesn't care about that.

Now we run `git stash -k -u`. `-k` tells stash not to touch the index, so it doesn't. Consider for a moment the first paragraph of the manpage for `stash`:

> Use git stash when you want to record the current state of the working directory and the index, but want to go back to a clean working directory.
>   The command saves your local modifications away and reverts the working directory to match the HEAD commit.

So: we have asked stash to save our local modifications (without touching the index), and revert the working directory to match the HEAD commit.
`file1` exists in the HEAD commit, so it comes back. But `file1` is no longer in the index, because we deleted it. Hence, `file1` is now an untracked file. Since we're not touching the index, the new file `boink` and the record that it was the result of a rename from `file1` remains in the index. Hence you get the potentially surprising output from `git status`:

```
Changes to be committed:    
        renamed:    file1 -> boink

Untracked files:
        file1
```

Answer (score 1):

There is output of your script. As you can see there is no `file3` and `file4` after unstash. This files appear after `stash -k`. Which is normal behaviour becouse `stash` restores deleted files. And -k make it keep index changes which is deletion `file3` from index. So you have both  `D file3` and `?? file3` at same time.

```
Initializing a fresh git dir...
rm: refusing to remove '.' or '..' directory: skipping '.'
rm: refusing to remove '.' or '..' directory: skipping '..'
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/azzel/projects/test/bash/gitstash/gitStashIssue/.git/

Preparing git state for test...
[master (root-commit) 7e891f6] initial commit
 4 files changed, 4 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 file1
 create mode 100644 file2
 create mode 100644 file3
 create mode 100644 file4
rm 'file3'

Current git status is:
MM file1
M  file2
D  file3
R  file4 -> fileRenamed
?? untrackedFile

Stasing changes...
Saved working directory and index state WIP on master: 7e891f6 initial commit

git status after stashing files is:
M  file1
M  file2
D  file3
R  file4 -> fileRenamed
?? file3
?? file4

cleaning up deleted and renamed files...
Removing file3
Removing file4

git status after cleanup:
M  file1
M  file2
D  file3
R  file4 -> fileRenamed

Commiting unstashed changes...
[master 1156712] commit unstashed changes
 4 files changed, 2 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)
 delete mode 100644 file3
 rename file4 => fileRenamed (100%)
Auto-merging file1
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in file1
Recorded preimage for 'file1'
Index was not unstashed.

git status after unstashing:
UU file1
?? untrackedFile
```